# XAML Horizontal Stackpanel Scrolling

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, horizontal-scrolling, stackpanel

I am having problems getting horizontal stackpanels to scroll from within a scrollviewer. What I'm trying to do is more complex than my example, but after removing variables I think I can figure everything out if I can solve this last problem.

Basically, I can't get a scrollviewer to scroll horizontally when it contains a horizontal stackpanel.

Here is the sample XAML:

```
   <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Strangely, if I just swap the orientation from Horizontal to Vertical, it scrolls just fine.  I've read on multiple posts that stackpanels have issues that can make them a poor fit for scrollviewers, so I tried it with a grid as well, but get the same results.

```
  <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="3"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="4"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Width="400" Height="400"  Grid.Column="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

It seems so simple that I feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.  If anyone can help out, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to turn on horizontal scrolling.  [It's hidden by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (but the vertical one is not, hence the confusion).

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: Thank you!  I skimmed over countless posts about the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility, and even looked at the MSDN link you posted, but I never realized that scrollbar visibility is required for scrolling to work.  
Thank you so much, I spent days on this.

Comment: What's crazy is that `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` must be enabled for touch-based scrolling to work, even when `HorizontalScrollMode` is enabled.